# How do I change my wallpaper? The picture on my desktop?

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background

I do not know how to change my desktop picture - the "wallpaper". Can anyone tell me how?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 now (although I was using 12.04 when I first asked the question).

Comment: Thanks for asking a straightforward question that we don't seem to have covered yet. Note that the details may vary from release to release, but the answer by llesh heads folks in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way to do this (at least on Ubuntu 20.04.3 which I'm running) is to right-click on the desktop, choose 'Display setttings' and then select 'Background'. If the picture you want isn't shown, at the top click on 'Add picture' and you can then navigate to the wallpaper you want to use in your system.

There's not much to choose one method over the other; if you choose the method I've given here, the minor advantage is that you can store a few wallpaper options in there and easily change from one to the other any time without having to navigate to the original file as the system stores the option for you to select and unselect at will.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to the picture file you want to use as your wallpaper, right click and choose **Set As Wallpaper**.

Comment: Note that in more recent Ubuntu releases, e.g. 20.04, the menu option to choose is "Change Background..."

Comment: I updated the old pc from 12.04 to 20.04.